# XAMPP Apache start failing after "magic_quotes_gpc=On"

Tags: apache, xampp

Hey guys i got an problem by starting my apache.
I try to install **xt-commerce** on my local machine. Here i had to change the entry in xampp/php/php.ini
**magic_quotes_gpc=Off -> On**

Since then my apache won't start anymore.

[my control panels seems like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmEZu.png)

and the apache error log entries:

```
[Fri Apr 01 18:30:56.550683 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 7476:tid 364] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Apr 01 18:31:05.089172 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 216:tid 364] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Apr 01 18:31:05.115173 2016] [core:warn] [pid 216:tid 364] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Fri Apr 01 18:31:05.251181 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 216:tid 364] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Apr 01 18:31:23.070200 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 6292:tid 364] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Apr 01 18:31:23.101202 2016] [core:warn] [pid 6292:tid 364] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Fri Apr 01 18:31:23.239210 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 6292:tid 364] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Apr 01 18:44:11.157132 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 4856:tid 364] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Apr 01 18:44:11.320141 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 4856:tid 364] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
```

what i've just tried to get it working:

- staring xampp control panel **as administrator**
- change ports **httpd.conf Listen 8081** and **httpd-ssl.conf Listen 444**
- turn off FW and AntiVir

i hope anybody knows what i have to do/change. :-/

Comment: Hallo Stefan, das gleiche Problem habe ich auch gerade. Hast du schon eine Lösung gefunden?